# Why encoding headers content type: text/html; is missing when use MailItem in Outlook plugin, whith the SMTP server of GMAIL: SMTP.GMAIL.COM?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-addin, mailmessage, mailitem

I try to send HTML to gmail account, from to gmail SMTP server.

If i write code like that and send HTML there is no problem.

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("aaaa@gmail.com", to, subject, body);
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtp);
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

        smtpClient.Port = 587;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
        smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

The email received in the gmail account is in base64
With the headers :

```
Subject: Test
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

`PGh0bWw==` **(this base 64 is not valid, it's only for the question)**

But if i use Outlook.MailItem to send my email there is what i get....

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


   <https://fdsafasdfasd.com/images/logo.png> =09

Cedric Boivin


cboivin@fadsfdasfads.com


Vous a envoy=E9 un message s=E9curis=E9 vifdasfasdfes
```

My text seen to be in clear, and not in HTML in Gmail. There is my code in Outlook Plugin

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem newMail = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                // newMail.Display(false);                                        
                newMail.Subject = subject;

                newMail.To = email.ToLower().Trim();
                newMail.Recipients.ResolveAll();
                newMail.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
                newMail.HTMLBody = htmlBody;
                newMail.Send();
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

In my send email, I was set some properties to the mailItem.

That was related to this article ...

[Prevent winmail.dat in outlook (for gmail accounts)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900976/prevent-winmail-dat-in-outlook-for-gmail-accounts)

if i remove them ... everything working fine.

Comment: Well done, maybe link to this answer on the variants you asked, bound to help someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

I tested with your Outlook mail code to send mails and I can correctly see the HTML formatted mails in my gmail account. My environment is: VS 2015 / Outlook 2016

Interestingly, in my testing I see both - `Content-Type: text/plain;` and `Content-Type: text/html;`. The code just sets the `HtmlBody` alone.

[image]

After you have sent the mail, if you look at your "Sent items" in Outlook - what is the format of the mail ?

Possibly something in your Outlook setting is converting it to plain text ! In older version of Outlook, there is an option to [convert to Plain text for specific users](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-message-format-to-HTML-Rich-Text-Format-or-plain-text-338a389d-11da-47fe-b693-cf41f792fefa#ID0EAABAAA=2010). By any chance are you using any of these version and have this option turned on ?

In my testing, I get your behaviour only if I set the `.Body` instead of `.HtmlBody`, i.e., `newMail.Body = htmlBody;`

Comment: You need to check in the Gmail received items. In outlook everything is fine.  You can also take a look on my post in the Microsoft Forum https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf09d3fa-27ba-4ac6-9959-d72247be5bf0/try-to-send-html-email-from-outlook-outlookmailitem-and-passing-by-gmail-smtp-server?forum=outlookdev

Comment: Another thought - Can you try to validate your HTML ? Is there something in your HTML that gmail doesn't like ?

Comment: Good question, i will try that

Comment: Did you send an email to a gmail account ? Or to another account ?